# Расшарить презентацию по ссылке на websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket

Добрый день.

У меня такая задача. Есть презентации. Я генерирую ссылку на презентацию, даю ее человеку, и он у себя на пк, перейдя по ней, моджет отслеживать переключение слайдов.

Как это можно реализвать на websocket?

Хотя бы принцип того, как это реализовывается.

Как это представляю я:

Не знаю как генерировать ссылку и привязывать к не сокет. Открываем сокет и шлем в него контент слайда. Человек подключается к сокету, получает контент и отображает у себя на мониторе.

Comment: https://socket.io/ Я думаю это подойдет для задачи

Comment: Как работать с websocket (socket.io) я знаю. Как генерацию ссылки сделать, ее же слушать надо.....? Как это организовать?

Comment: @ks_on_v Зачем вебсокет для презентации? И как вы вообще себе представляете передачу презентации через вебсокет, а главное зачем? Презентацию можно отдать с сервера как статическую страницу. И причем тут react.js?

Comment: Затем, что мне надо отдать ссылку на презентацию. Когда я у себя буду менять слайды, они должны и у пользователя (которому я дал ссылку) меняться. В реалтайме отображать у всех текущий слайд.